# How should I modify a node's attributes using the graph gem when outside of a digraph block?

Tags: ruby, graph, graphviz

### What Works Easily

I find that working with a digraph block from the [graph gem](https://github.com/seattlerb/graph) works well if the code is encapsulated in a block rather than composed at run-time. For example:

```
require "graph"
digraph do
  doublecircle << node("goal")  
  save "example", "png"  
end
```

will correctly render as follows:

[image: the expected goal node]

### What Doesn't Work So Well

My goal is to (eventually) build and modify nodes and edges at run-time, but I feel like I'm struggling against the gem's framework whenever I try to work with instantiated graph objects outside of a digraph block. For example, even after reading the source of the [graph.rb library](https://github.com/seattlerb/graph/blob/master/lib/graph.rb), I can't seem to fully grok how to modify an already-instantiated Graph object by adding/removing nodes or adjusting individual node attributes on the fly.

For example, I have managed to get the following to work through a great deal of trial-and-error:

```
require "graph"
graph = Graph.new
graph.node "goal"
graph.nodes["goal"].attributes.push digraph.doublecircle
graph.save "example", "png"
```

While this seems to work, it doesn't scale well and it *feels* like a brute-force kludge rather than leveraging the gem's intended approach. To my mind, the code above lacks both elegance and a real understanding of the optimal patterns to manipulate the node and attribute data structures.

Ultimately, I want to be able to modify the digraph at run-time by adding and removing nodes and edges on the fly in response to user input. Is there a more canonical approach to this particular use case? Am I just missing something fundamental in my understanding of this gem's Graph class, or is there a better solution for what I'm trying to accomplish?